# authorization users and roles in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I am pretty new to asp.net. I want to use authorization in web.config file in my project and to create roles.I do not exactly know what is this roles and where and how I can define roles that uses in authorization as in code below?

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles ="admin"/> 
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```